trino large query is failing due to hive metastore failure
I have a large insert into query, which is reaching 99-100% quite fast (after 5-6 min), then completion percent starting to decrease and back to high number and repeating..
This query is reading from multiple table that are bucketed (not all tables have same num of buckets) and target table is not bucketed, only partitioned by event_date which we have only one in this query.
I see the attached error in master server log. hive failure.
in each trino server we have hive container which is handling hive operations to metastore in rds.
do you have any suggestion for solution?
In addition, do you have any recommended params to set that can help working with buckets to be more efficient? (I use a few but wanted to hear your experience)
Infra: EMR 6.15.0 , trino 424
Will be happy to provide more info if needed.
Thanks
hive conf:
{
"Classification": "trino-connector-hive",
"Properties": {
"hive.recursive-directories": "true",
"hive.metastore-cache-ttl": "120s",
"hive.metastore-timeout": "30m",
"hive.non-managed-table-writes-enabled": "true",
"hive.parquet.use-column-names": "true",
"hive.insert-existing-partitions-behavior": "OVERWRITE",
"hive.metastore.uri": "thrift://localhost:9084",
"hive.allow-register-partition-procedure": "true",
"hive.max-partitions-per-writers": "1000",
"hive.s3-file-system-type": "TRINO",
"hive.metastore-refresh-interval": "120s",
"hive.s3.max-connections": "100000"
}
then i tried also with 100 max partition per writers and still failed.
logs:
trino master server log error 2024-10-30T13:18:00.804Z ERROR stage-scheduler io.trino.execution.scheduler.PipelinedQueryScheduler Failure in distributed stage for query 20241030_130249_00005_ctevz io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Failed connecting to Hive metastore: [localhost:9084] heduling 6ms :: running 30ms :: finishing 7ms :: begin 2024-10-30T13:17:48.985Z :: end 2024-10-30T13:17:49.031Z 2024-10-30T13:18:00.782Z ERROR remote-task-callback-1750 io.trino.execution.scheduler.PipelinedStageExecution Pipelined stage execution for stage 20241030_130249_00005_ctevz.1 failed io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Failed connecting to Hive metastore: [localhost:9084] at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastore.getTable(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:321) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.BridgingHiveMetastore.getTable(BridgingHiveMetastore.java:93) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.ForwardingHiveMetastore.getTable(ForwardingHiveMetastore.java:63) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore.loadTable(CachingHiveMetastore.java:607) at com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader$FunctionToCacheLoader.load(CacheLoader.java:169) at io.trino.cache.EvictableCache$TokenCacheLoader.load(EvictableCache.java:447) at io.trino.cache.EvictableCache$TokenCacheLoader.load(EvictableCache.java:433) at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3571) at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2313) at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2190) at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2080) at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4012) at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4035) at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:5011) at io.trino.cache.EvictableCache.get(EvictableCache.java:145) at com.google.common.cache.AbstractLoadingCache.getUnchecked(AbstractLoadingCache.java:53) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore.getOptional(CachingHiveMetastore.java:451) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore.getTable(CachingHiveMetastore.java:596) at io.trino.plugin.hive.HiveMetastoreClosure.getPartition(HiveMetastoreClosure.java:237) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.HivePageSinkMetadataProvider.getPartition(HivePageSinkMetadataProvider.java:55) at io.trino.plugin.hive.HiveWriterFactory.createWriter(HiveWriterFactory.java:329) at io.trino.plugin.hive.HivePageSink.getWriterIndexes(HivePageSink.java:409) at io.trino.plugin.hive.HivePageSink.writePage(HivePageSink.java:303) at io.trino.plugin.hive.HivePageSink.doAppend(HivePageSink.java:297) at io.trino.plugin.hive.HivePageSink.lambda$appendPage$3(HivePageSink.java:285) at io.trino.hdfs.authentication.HdfsAuthentication.lambda$doAs$0(HdfsAuthentication.java:26) at io.trino.hdfs.authentication.UserGroupInformationUtils.lambda$executeActionInDoAs$0(UserGroupInformationUtils.java:29) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399) at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1876) at io.trino.hdfs.authentication.UserGroupInformationUtils.executeActionInDoAs(UserGroupInformationUtils.java:27) at io.trino.hdfs.authentication.ImpersonatingHdfsAuthentication.doAs(ImpersonatingHdfsAuthentication.java:41) at io.trino.hdfs.authentication.HdfsAuthentication.doAs(HdfsAuthentication.java:25) at io.trino.hdfs.HdfsEnvironment.doAs(HdfsEnvironment.java:128) at io.trino.plugin.hive.HivePageSink.appendPage(HivePageSink.java:285) at io.trino.plugin.base.classloader.ClassLoaderSafeConnectorPageSink.appendPage(ClassLoaderSafeConnectorPageSink.java:68) at io.trino.operator.TableWriterOperator.addInput(TableWriterOperator.java:255) at io.trino.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:400) at io.trino.operator.Driver.lambda$process$8(Driver.java:298) at io.trino.operator.Driver.tryWithLock(Driver.java:694) at io.trino.operator.Driver.process(Driver.java:290) at io.trino.operator.Driver.processForDuration(Driver.java:261) at io.trino.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:887) at io.trino.execution.executor.timesharing.PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(PrioritizedSplitRunner.java:187) at io.trino.execution.executor.timesharing.TimeSharingTaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(TimeSharingTaskExecutor.java:565) at io.trino.$gen.Trino_426____20241030_124135_2.run(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TException: Failed connecting to Hive metastore: [localhost:9084] at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.StaticTokenAwareMetastoreClientFactory.createMetastoreClient(StaticTokenAwareMetastoreClientFactory.java:116) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.UgiBasedMetastoreClientFactory.createMetastoreClientFor(UgiBasedMetastoreClientFactory.java:50) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastore.createMetastoreClient(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:2050) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastore.lambda$getTable$4(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:312) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftMetastoreApiStats.lambda$wrap$0(ThriftMetastoreApiStats.java:41) at io.trino.plugin.hive.util.RetryDriver.run(RetryDriver.java:116) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastore.getTable(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:311) ... 48 more Suppressed: org.apache.thrift.TException: Failed connecting to Hive metastore: [localhost:9084] ... 55 more Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: localhost:9084: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.Transport.rewriteException(Transport.java:95) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.Transport.create(Transport.java:54) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.DefaultThriftMetastoreClientFactory.createTransport(DefaultThriftMetastoreClientFactory.java:129) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.DefaultThriftMetastoreClientFactory.lambda$create$0(DefaultThriftMetastoreClientFactory.java:107) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastoreClient.connect(ThriftHiveMetastoreClient.java:156) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastoreClient.(ThriftHiveMetastoreClient.java:150) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.DefaultThriftMetastoreClientFactory.create(DefaultThriftMetastoreClientFactory.java:113) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.DefaultThriftMetastoreClientFactory.create(DefaultThriftMetastoreClientFactory.java:107) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.StaticTokenAwareMetastoreClientFactory.getClient(StaticTokenAwareMetastoreClientFactory.java:122) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.StaticTokenAwareMetastoreClientFactory.createMetastoreClient(StaticTokenAwareMetastoreClientFactory.java:108) ... 54 more Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.Transport.createRaw(Transport.java:88) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.Transport.create(Transport.java:46) ... 62 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:547) at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602) at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.Transport.createRaw(Transport.java:69) ... 63 more Suppressed: org.apache.thrift.TException: Failed connecting to Hive metastore: [localhost:9084] ... 55 more Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: localhost:9084: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
